# Is there a way to change tint of selected pixels in a Sprite?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Hello dear StackOverflow's community!

This is my very first question on the site, so I hope I'll be clear enough. Also, I am a French guy and I apologize in advance for the language mistakes!

Let me explain my situation (I like to be precise so it will be a bit long) :

I am currently doing an internship in my University. Here's the topic : my teacher made a 2D serious game based on image processing, where each player (4 maximum) must replace the right colors on each part of an animal. She used the XNA framework of Visual Studio to do it.
My task is to develop a new version of this game using Javascript technologies, particularly Pixi.js.

The game works like this : the main Container of the application is separated in 4 areas, one per player ; each of these areas sets its background using a Sprite that I create from the grey-scaled image of the animal the player chosed. At the center of the screen is a color palette represented by an array of Sprites. From this I can drag n' drop a color to the animal Sprite, and the region that represents a part of its body detects the drop. Everything works fine until here, but this is the point where I encounter difficulties.

I would like to change the tint of only the pixels corresponding to this region. The positions of these pixels are registered in an array I create from a text file, that's how I can detect which region receives the color.

I already tried to use a Graphics object from Pixi to redraw the color above the Sprite, but it is extremely slow. I also tried to use Filter, but since I want to color only some pixels and not the entire Sprite, I need to pass (using uniforms) the array of positions to my WebGL shader to make it verify for each pixel if it is part of the ones I want to change. But the shader needs me to declare this array indicating its size. I cannot do that because every region has a different number of pixels.

I am blocked now, and I don't know how to perform what I want...

Is there any solution that does not imply separating my image in several Sprites? I think it would work but if there can be another way, allowing me to avoid this, I would be very thankful!

Thanks in advance, and sorry that this message is so long!

Comment: This depends how ok you are with shaders (as I'm personally not, I don't want to touch them :D). But I would imagine you could do it so, that you make a shader that replaces the colors of your choosing with something else, so a shader kinda like this: http://codepen.io/mishaa/pen/emGNXE (doesn't seem to work, but I think you get the idea).
Personally I would probably use multiple images (as you mention) to make the manipulation, unless you really really need to optimize loading times or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!
Since I have issues with the understanding of WebGL shaders I will try the second solution : using several Sprites per image.
At least it will be possible to perform some tests and see the results!

Comment: After a first try I got my answer for the multiple images solution...
Unfortunately my app gets slow with multiple Sprites for each image. I've seen the movement of the dragged objects getting jerky as I was rendering a single image made of 9 superimposed Sprites.
First I thought about my update() method, because the renderer.render() method is called in it, and all the screen is re-drawn something like 100 times per second. But all the colors in the palette are Sprites too. It seems the number of displayed objects is not involved in this problem.
Will continue my tries with WebGL shaders!

Comment: I was away, didn't see this in a while, so sorry for late response. I just started to rethink about that. If you have only 4 layers and each layer has one picture of an animal and the animal has e.g. 10 diffrerent parts to color, it still only makes like 40 images (plus palette sprites). It doesn't sound very big, especially when using webGL. To me it sounds like it should work without special shaders too and there is something else slowing it down.

Comment: Also another thing is that most of the sprites are static on your stage / containers, which also makes it more efficient as they don't really need updating, only the part that changes color needs to change.

Comment: I ended up using node-opencv for image processing! Since my case is very specific it wouldn't have been very efficient to use Pixi only for such a job. I directly modify the image files in my node server then I send them back to the client using socket.io. Not very conventional I know, but the important thing is that it works!
Thanks though, for your advices and observations, Hachi =)